# Luminoth: Duration of default Google Cloud ML training job with voc2012

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, google-cloud-ml

I used [luminoth](https://github.com/tryolabs/luminoth) (checked out from GIT) with default settings, dataset voc2012 (transformed and uploaded to a bucket) and the sample_config.yml

How long should the job approximately take? Because I got it running - but now it's running since over 40h and still didn't complete!?

Or do I have to stop it manually?

Answer (score 1):

It appears from the [source code](https://github.com/tryolabs/luminoth/blob/0c5a73fd22af3ad8bb51902d98323c2d2636de64/luminoth/train.py#L187)  that luminoth trains until you stop it (locally that would be ctrl-c; on the cloud, manually cancelling the job).

I suppose the idea is to monitor tensorboard while it's training and manually stop it when it looks good.

Comment: thanks @rhaertel80 , can I use tensorboard for monitoring somehow? I only know how to use it for local jobs..

Comment: Run tensorboard exactly the same way (e.g. on your local machine), but set the output directory to the GCS location you've specified (probably what you set as --job-dir)

Comment: yes I already tried: tensorboard --logdir gs://path/to/job  ..but it results in an exception "tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: File system scheme gs not implemented"

Comment: How did you install TensorFlow. There's an option to compile in GCS support. I thought it was on by default if you pip install it, but I'm not certain. If you compile from source, you have to select the option during configure because it's off by default.

Comment: via pip3 install.. it's also discussed here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11280

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: From the GitHub issue you linked, sounds like GCS support doesn't work on Windows (probably because it requires libcurl). On Windows you'll be stuck downloading the files periodically with gsutil. If you have access to Ubuntu that would be better.